How to do YAML schema validation using Cerberus?
I am trying to develop a validation schema for my project and I need some help.
The YAML file looks like something below
label: sample
version: 1
parameters:
  - columns : [Name]
    metadata:
      type: pii-string
  - columns : [Age]
    metadata:
      type: pii-number
      args:
        mask_value: XX
  - columns : [city]
    metadata:
      type: location
      args:
        default_value: IND

The parameters is a dict that has columns and metadata. The metadata field contains extra arguments for certain types such as pii, work_location etc. The args might differ for each metadata type.
I am trying to validate this YAML using cerberus. However I am not able to figure the logic for how to validate certain args for certain metadata.
For example:

If the metadata type is "pii_number", then args should have mask_value
If the metadata type is "location", args should have "default_value".

This is what I have currently, I am trying to just do a general validation for args type. So if the metadata dict has certain args, then it passes. Its not metadata specific.  How can I change this to make it metadata specific?
"label": {"type": "string", "required": True},
"version": {"type": "integer", "required": True},
"parameters": {
    "type": "list",
    "schema": {
        "type": "dict",
        "schema": {
            "columns": {"type": "list", "required": True},
            "metadata": {
                "type": "dict",
                "required": True,
                "schema": {
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "allowed": ["pii-string", "pii-number", "location"],
                        "required": True,
                    },
                    "args": {
                        "type": "dict",
                        "allowed": ["mask_value", "default_value"],
                        "required": False
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

Please help and Thanks in advance

That YAML is a bit inconsistent with both double and single quoted scalars, all of which are superfluous.
